# Docker Tomcat Container giving 404 while running servlet

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, amazon-ec2, servlets

I am getting this error when I run my Docker container built using my application's war file:

`HTTP Status 404 – Not Found`

`Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`

The URL I am using is `http://<public DNS of my linux machine>:8085/`.

`http://ec2-18-188-198-18.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8085`

The linux machine is an AWS EC2 instance created from a linux AMI

I am running docker from this machine.

These are my docker container port details i got by using `docker ps`
[image]

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:9
COPY app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Here is one of my servlet files as a reference to the kind of java code that is being used in rest of the files

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
@WebServlet("/")
public class AdminLogin extends HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
```

As you can see I am using javax.servlets.* in my code rather than jakarta.servlets.*

Normally this problem should occur if I would have used tomcat 10 but I am using tomcat 9 with javax.servlets.*.

So I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by making changes to the Dockerfile and the URL being hit.

This is the new Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:9.0-jdk11
RUN cp -r $CATALINA_HOME/webapps.dist/* $CATALINA_HOME/webapps
COPY app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
```

This is the new URL:
`http://<public DNS of my linux machine>:8085/<name of war file>`

`http://ec2-18-188-198-18.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8085/app`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this article can give you an explanation what is happening:
https://forums.docker.com/t/tomcat-give-error-404/95130

> Based on the community request, Webapps folder is moved to the
> webapps.dist folder, which means webapps folder is empty and there are
> no files to serve on the browser. That is when you saw the error
> message The origin server did not find a current representation for
> the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.